# Error when installing pr2-simulator

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,I was following this tutorial *Starting PR2 in Simulation* and I understood that I needed to install pr2 simulator first. So I have executed:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-pr2-simulator
```

---

And this is what I got:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-kinetic-pr2-simulator
```

I have just started using ROS, and I don't know much about this world

Thank you in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242905/error-when-installing-pr2-simulator/) by [lucadg](https://answers.ros.org/users/27866/lucadg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2016-09-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Found the right command on http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_roslaunch

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-pr2-common
```

---

Originally posted by [lucadg](https://answers.ros.org/users/27866/lucadg/) with karma: 63 on 2016-09-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1